# create nCloths out of selected objects with python?

Tags: python, maya, mel

I'm just getting started in python/MEL scripting and was wondering if there was a way to turn selected items into nCloths within python. I know in the software you would just select the objects you want and click 'create nCloth'. When I do that I get the following MEL script in the terminal -

createNCloth 0;

Is there a way to do this in python only? Or does this have to be a Mel/Python hybrid?

Answer (score 0):

If you run this command in a `MEL` tab in your Maya Script Editor, you'll get:

```
whatIs createNCloth;
// Result: Script found in: C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2018/scripts/others/createNCloth.mel //
```

Looking through the `createNCloth.mel` script briefly, it looks somewhat involved. You can call this script yourself from python via the `maya.mel` module, which unfortunately is often the way things go with some of these specialised Maya integrations.

Keep in mind that the `createNCloth(<worldSpace>)` proc expects your mesh to be selected, and will not let you pass an object as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

@itypewithmyhands gave you the method to find what is inside a MEL proc.

Note that it is a lot of checks to control user selection and it is mainly doing this :

```
# create a cloth node
cmds.createNode("nCloth")

# connect time node 
cmds.connectAttr("time1.outTime", nCloth + ".currentTime")

# connect your mesh to the ncloth 
cmds.connectAttr(mesh + ".worldMesh", nCloth + ".inputMesh")

# create an output shape that will be the simulation mesh
outMesh = cmds.createNode("mesh", parent=tform, name=outMeshName)
cmds.connectAttr(nCloth + ".outputMesh", outMesh + ".inMesh")

# connect the startframe
cmds.connectAttr(nucleus + ".startFrame", nCloth + ".startFrame")

# Connect the cloth node to the nucleus with an available ID
cmds.connectAttr(nCloth + ".currentState", nucleus +".inputActive[{}]".format(nindex), f=1)
cmds.connectAttr(nCloth + ".startState", nucleus + ".inputActiveStart[{}]", f=1)

# force the refresh when used in batch
cmds.getAttr(cloth + ".forceDynamics")
```

So those are the mandatory steps to replicate a basic cloth network. Note that you have also to create the nucleus, maybe check if the base mesh is deformed, you might want to set as intermediate shape the input mesh... etc